# Change Android status bar color along with an ongoing notification

Tags: android, notifications, statusbar

I'm trying to get the status bar to change color as long as a certain ongoing notification is active in the status bar. I think this is what happens when you answer a call on your phone and you minimize the phone app. (The status bar changes color to show that you are still in the call.) I've read the [Notification docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#PRIORITY_HIGH) and other search results but couldn't find anything helpful.

Does anyone know how to do achieve this? (Or help confirm that this is not possible/is bad design?)

Thanks!

Comment: Did you end up finding a method to do this?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. I didn't look into it further after I stopped working on that project.